# will win 7 ask for password to sync files

Tags: encryption

I have an Android phone. It is encrypted. It has a password to login. I connected this to a Windows 7 computer. It shows it's connected as a media device.

1. Was wondering if Windows 7 computer can sync the files of my android phone without asking for the password ?
2. Lets say it somehow did get the files, will the files be encrypted with a password or would they be decrypted already before the transfer was over to the win7 computer ?

The big CAVEAT is that I was using my phone While it was connected to the PC and hence the phone was Unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `Media Transfer Protocol`, the phone handles all the encryption/decryption while transferring files.

The Windows7/AnyOther PC cannot access the files on device till the device is connected and phone's screen is unlocked.

Windows7 will never ask your phone unlock password or any other passwords. All it needs is the device to be connected and lockscreen unlocked. The rest of file transfer will be handled by phone.

All outgoing files from the device are decrypted and sent. And all incoming files to the device are encrypted and stored.

Comment: What folder do the files go to ? Are they synced by some program automatically ?

Comment: They are never synced automatically. They are only copied or moved to the location you explicitly choose from windows explorer.